# Change strings in Javascript with replace() based on index

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following string

```js
let string = "01,15,01,45"
```

Which i want to turn to this

```js
string = "01:15 - 01:45"
```

but i'm only able to come up with

```js
"01,15,01,45".replace(/,/g, ':') // Gives "01:15:01:45"
```

but then i'm not sure how to get the index of the 5th position in string and replace it to `' - '`

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: if the length is known, you can just do `"01,15,01,45".replace(/(\d\d),(\d\d),(\d\d),(\d\d)/, "$1:$2 - $3:$4")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try doing things in one step when it would be clearer as multiple steps.

```
let string = "01,15,01,45";
let parts = string.split(",");
let result = `${parts[0]}:${parts[1]} - ${parts[2]}:${parts[3]}`;
```

Comment: When you get so fixated on solving your problamatic approach and you forget other simpler solutions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "01,15,01,45";

stringArray=string.split(',');

firstInterval=stringArray.slice(0, stringArray.length/2);
```

Output: `["01", "15"]`

```
secondInterval=stringArray.slice(stringArray.length/2,stringArray.length);
```

Output:`["01", "45"]`

```
firstIntervalString=firstInterval[0]+":"+firstInterval[1];
```

Output: `"01:15"`

```
secondIntervalString=secondInterval[0]+":"+secondInterval[1];
```

Output: `"01:45"`

```
completeInterval=firstIntervalString+" - "+secondIntervalString;
```

Output: `"01:15 - 01:45"`

I think the code is self-explanatory. Still, please feel free to let me know if any part is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with matching pairs and replacing leftover commas.

```js
let string = "01,15,01,45",
    result = string.match(/\d\d,\d\d/g).map(p => p.replace(/\,/, ':')).join(' - ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz